# Sending bulk / single emails from a single domain

Tags: email, email-server, spam, email-bounces, sendgrid

Let me explain our situation:

We have a web application that uses subdomains for each customer instance:

- customer1.example.com
- customer2.example.com

Every instance can have over 500 users, which all have entered their own email address. We send different kinds of emails to these users. If a newsletter is sent for example, an email has to go out to 500+ users (bulk)(contents are slightly different). But on other occasions we send emails to single users (reset password, reminders...). We also have applications that can 'manage' different instances of our application. From their own application they can send notifications to all users in all their associated application instances (for example 5000 users).

Replying to emails that people receive is not necessary, so we could a no-reply@...... (but then that email has to exist? We have over 13k instances, does that mean 13k no-reply addresses?)

The user receiving the email should see that the email comes from their instance name (customer1).

There is not an email for every instance like mail@customer2.example.com

Currently we are having loads of problems with bounced emails. We are classified as spam, even though we send our emails through SendGrid (shared IP). We are positive that none of the emails that are sent are spam.

How should we send our emails? What sender / from / reply-to.... headers should we use? How can we minimize our bounce rates?

Comment: @Basaa You are likely getting classified as spam because one or more of your senders is not using a proper opt-in strategy.  Blacklists often use spam trap addresses to identify spammers, not the content of the messages.  This capture sender who send unwanted email (SPAM).  There are several sites which outline proper bulk emailing processes.  Your high bounce rates indicate you are NOT following them.

Comment: If you want to obfuscate the domain, don't just pick a random domain name that MAY belongs to someone else - use **example.(com|net|org)** which is meant for this.

Answer (score 0):

This look like a duplicate, except for one point that can help there as if you got only some major client;

Ask you customer 1 and 2 to whitelist your IP from where the email come out.

Dont forget that bulk send if you use your ISP SMTP will make you flagged for spam. By scripting or in programming slow down the rate per minute, for other tip please check @masegaloeh link